# How did select annotation title?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How tap or clickable annotation title in Map. For example I have code:

```
@IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Map.delegate = self
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, lon!)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Title"
    Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

}
```

I try use `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` but it doesn't work. Maybe someone have any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the delegate methods.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "Pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true

        let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    print(#function)
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        // Do something
    }
}
```